# Max Number of keys in Mongoose Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose in my app. I wanted to know whats the max number of keys that the schema can have and still provide optimum performance?
I am asking this question as there are certain schema's in my app which will have many keys(approximately 12), therefore I was thinking if required I can make another schema using the reference id of the original for storing extra info. So I wanted to know the information. 
Here I am asking about performance of both the mongo-db and mongoose.

Comment: 12 keys is not a lot of keys.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: Do you mean indexes (you're using the word "keys")? There is a max in MongoDB (64 I believe), but practically speaking, exceeding even 16 is too many. Fewer is far better for MongoDB, especially for DBs with lots of writing, as every document must be processed for each collection and each index.

Comment: No I meant keys only. Indexes are on only 2 3 of these.